# Некорректо запускаются функции в Си

Tags: c

Написала программу на Си, с двумя функциями: подсчёт символов в тексте и подсчёт слов. Решила добавить запуск функции по вводимому числу(1 или 2). Сам запуск работает, но когда функция открывается, она не принимает текст на ввод (выводит в качестве результата подсчёта 0 символов). Сами по себе функции рабочие. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. win 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IN 0
#define OUT -1
#define F1 1
#define F2 2

int symbols()  //F1
{
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    printf("\nEnter the text = ");
    for(int i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n';)
    {
        count++;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf(" = %d symbol(s)", count);
    return 0;
}

int words()  //F2
{
    int count1 = 0;
    char c;
    int state = OUT;
    printf("\nEnter the text = ");
    for(int i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n';)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t' 
        || c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7' || c == '8' || c == '9'
        || c == '.' || c == '-' || c == ',' || c == '!' || c == '?' || c == '"' || c == ':' || c == ';' || c == '^' || c == '{'
        || c == '#' || c == '@' || c == '&' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '_' || c == '=' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '}'
        || c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%' || c == '$')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT) 
        {
            state = IN;
            count1++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf(" = %d word(s)\n", count1);
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{   
    int function = 0;
    printf("\nEnter the number of function");
    scanf(&function);
    if(function == F1) symbols(); 
        else if(function == F2) words();
            else printf("ERROR: the name of function is not correct");
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали? Попробуйте.

Comment: И что, это - `scanf(&function);` - у вас работает?

Comment: Компилятор выдал вам диагностические сообщения, указывающие как минимум на самые грубые из ваших ошибок. Почему вы проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас return(прочитать про return в функции [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sta56yeb.aspx)) возвращает 0 в обоих частях, в таком случае я сделал бы их void и вообще не возвращал ничего.
Вы выводите буквы через for, хотя можно было бы избавиться и от него.
Ответ заключается в том, что вы: 
а)Используете одну и ту же переменную во вложенном цикле(i);
б)Не используете 3го параметра в for'е(я бы использовал while на вашем месте, прочитать про него можно [тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/352/))
в)Используйте scanf с форматом в начале(про него можно прочитать [тут](http://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/13/scanf.html))